# XML file error: Entity not defined

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, app-config

Im using Visual Studio 2012, have here a C# project and of course I'm using an `App.config` in my project. Everything was fine, until I added something like this:

```
<add key="myChar" value="&sup2;"/>
```

Error:

```
Entity 'sup2' not defined
```

Well sup2 should represent `²` as like `&qout;` is representing `"`. For `&qout;` I do not get any error. Why? Im still able to compile, but I want to get rid of this message - or understand why it's an error for VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only a small subset of such entities that are valid for XML - those that escape parts of XML markup itself:

- quot
- amp
- apos
- lt
- gt

There are many more for various bits of syntax in HTML.

[Reference (sorry its WikiPedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML)

Comment: Uh oh, so my ² was only for HTML. Thought I can use these also for XML - well somehow I cannot :) Thx